# iReSign: Resigning IPA which was created with older (now expired) provisioning profile

Tags: ios

I am trying to resign IPA which was created with older enterprise profile. The older enterprise profile is expired now and I have a new enterprise profile installed (*.mobileprovision).

Question: Is it possible to resign IPA which was created with older enterprise profile using iReSign tool? Now, I am trying to resign with new provisioning profile.

I am using iReSign tool (https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign).

I entered following details:

- path to ipa (which was created with older profile)
- path to .mobileprovision (new provisioning profile)
- Certificate name

I get this error:

```
Signing failed /var/folders/vv/plljljdj5mqc3g0gc5wnv7fr0000gq/T/com.appulize.iresign/Payload/AppName.app: replacing existing signature codesign_allocate: object: /private/var/folders/vv/plljljdj5mqc3g0gc5wnv7fr0000gq/T/com.appulize.iresign/Payload/AppName.app/AppName malformed object (unknown load command 21) /var/folders/vv/plljljdj5mqc3g0gc5wnv7fr0000gq/T/com.appulize.iresign/Payload/AppName.app:
**object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable**

/var/folders/vv/plljljdj5mqc3g0gc5wnv7fr0000gq/T/com.appulize.iresign/Payload/AppName.app:
**invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)** In architecture: armv7
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your IPA's code signature is still valid, `xcrun` should work fine:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v -o `pwd`/out.ipa --sign YourSigningIdentity --embed new.mobileprovision your.app
```

If `xcrun` complains about signatures, you can manually resign and repackage

```
cp new.mobileprovision your.app/embedded.mobileprovision
codesign -f -s YourSigningIdentity --resource-rules your.app/ResourceRules.plist your.app 
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v -o `pwd`/out.ipa your.app
```